# Windows 8.1 Prism - Views in Multiple Projects

Tags: c#, prism, windows-8.1

I'm using Prism for Windows 8.1 Apps and I would like to have multiple projects that contain views in the solution structure.  The problem is that the View/VM locator can't seem to find the views in projects other than the one containing App.xaml

The view are inheriting from VisualStateAwarePage and using the same namespace that the locator is searching for the views.

Has anyone used views in separate projects?  Any idea what might be missing?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Are you sure you are registering the views in your `IModule` class in the class library projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation on page 36 (of the downloaded PDF version) is the answer for this:

Changing the convention for naming, locating and associating viewmodels with views. Online you will find it under

[Use this link to the documentation](https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/documentation)

The same thing in the online version is at [this location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130642.aspx). Scroll until you see the paragraph title I mentioned above.

Good luck!